# How to make an alias for Kubectl in Windows using ENV Variables?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-10, environment-variables, command-line-interface

I've created a folder called `Aliases` in `C:\` and added `C:\Aliases` to Environment Variables.
Inside the folder I've created a file `K.bat` with contents :

```
kubectl
```

however when I run `k get pods` it doesn't return a string , only executes the kubectl command without any parameters after it.

How can we fix this ?

Answer (score 8):

The simpler anwser is to rename the kubectl command or use doskey you can execute this at startup.

```
doskey k=kubectl $*
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `%*` to pass on all command line arguments in a batch script.

Therefore, your `k.bat` or `k.cmd` file would look like this:

```
@echo off
kubectl %*
```

This will create you the `k` alias for `kubectl` on Windows.

I have a similar shortcut for minikube, with some added logic for determining if the parameter should be sent to minikube or kubectl:

```
@echo off
set DIRECT_COMMANDS=:start:status:stop:delete:dashboard:pause:unpause:docker-env:podman-env:cache:image:addons:config:profile:update-context:service:tunnel:mount:ssh:kubectl:node:ssh-key:ssh-host:ip:update-check:version:options:completion:

echo:%DIRECT_COMMANDS%|findstr /c::%1% >NUL 2>&1

if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
  minikube %*
) else (
  minikube kubectl -- %*
)
```

Answer (score 3):

on power shell if kubectl is added to env

```bash
New-Alias -Name "k" kubectl
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want a command with agruments to be treated as macros, use `"$*"` in the end, like you do it with alias in *nix:

```
alias kn='kubectl config set-context --current --namespace'
```

with doskey will be:

```
doskey kn=kubectl config set-context --current --namespace "$*
```