# How do I use "kubectl" instead of the path to the kubectl.exe in Powershell

Tags: powershell, kubernetes, environment-variables, alias, kubectl

When I run Kubernetes commands, Powershell is wanting me to use the path to the kubectl.exe instead of just using the command kubectl.

I'm told using an Alias would work but I'm not sure how to do that in this case with Powershell and my attempts have come up fruitless.

This is what I tried:

[How to make an alias for Kubectl in Windows using ENV Variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65855456/how-to-make-an-alias-for-kubectl-in-windows-using-env-variables)

I tried running this:
`C:\Aliases> New-Item -ItemType File -Path C:\Aliases\"K.bat" -Value "doskey k=kubectl $*" -Force`

And made a system Environment Variable with Aliases as the name and C:\Aliases as the value.

typing K, k, kubectl, etc. was not returning anything that looked like it was being set as an alias.

Answer (score 1):

Place the following in your [`$PROFILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) file (open it for editing with, e.g., `notepad $PROFILE`; if it doesn't exist, create it with `New-Item -Force $PROFILE` first):

```
Set-Alias k kubectl.exe
```

If `kubectl.exe` isn't in a directory listed in `$env:PATH`, specify the full path instead (substitute the real directory path below):

```
Set-Alias k 'C:\path\to\kubectl.exe'
```

This allows you to invoke `kubectl.exe` with `k` in future sessions.

(The post you link to is for `cmd.exe` (Command Prompt), not PowerShell.)